# PowerShell Script to Create a New SPDiagnosticsCategory

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Powershell script to create a new SPDiagnosticsCategory under an custom SPDiagnosticService.Areas["MY_AREA"]

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe this is possible in SharePoint 2010. In SharePoint 2007 the ULS logging worked a little differently, and it was possible to register/unregister new categories, but in SharePoint 2010 it appears that these have to be built into your implementation of the SPDiagnosticsServiceBase class. [See here for details](http://www.novolocus.com/2011/06/27/my-logging-diagnostics-service-for-sharepoint-2010/).